# Java EE @Inject

Tags: java, java-ee

При добавлении зависимости UsersDao

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("private/users/")
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    private UsersDao usersDao;

    @POST
    @Path("/set")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response setUser (UsersDto usersDto){
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка компиляции

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type UsersDao with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ru.orgunit.rest.UserResource.usersDao
  at ru.orgunit.rest.UserResource.usersDao(UserResource.java:0)
```

Класс Users

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Users extends SuperEntity {
    @Transient
    public static final String SYSTEM_CREATOR = "system";

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

При добавлении инжекте обычного интерфеса всё работает.

Мой beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Comment: Вы сами, сами-то читали текст ошибки? Почему нет кода UserDao? Считаете, что бесполезный Users поможет определить причину?

Comment: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Провал развёртывания CDI:WELD-001408: Неудовлетворённая зависимость для типа UsersDao с квалификатором @@Default
  в точке внедрения [BackedAnnotatedField] @@Inject private ru.orgunit.rest.UserResource.usersDao
  в ru.orgunit.rest.UserResource.usersDao(UserResource.java:0) Не видит CDI Ваш UsersDao. Почему? Да пёс его знает.